# Nodejs unit testing with redis-mock results in ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redis

I'm currently having a class in NodeJS which will create a redis client when being instantiated. I am trying to write a unit test to test this class. However, I am unsure to to get the main code work with the redis-mock use in the unit test.

During the unit test, this line of code returned `redis.createClient(config.get('redis.port'), config.get('redis.ip'));` -> `connect ECONNREFUSED`

```
class Socket {

    constructor(socketClient) {

        /** For socket io */
        this.socketClient = socketClient;
        log.info("new socketio client connected... " + socketClient.id);        
        
        /** For redis */
        // a redis client is created and connects
        this.redisClient = redis.createClient(config.get('redis.port'), config.get('redis.ip'));

        this.redisClient.on('connect', function() {
            log.info('Redis client connected ' + socketClient.id);
        });
        this.redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
            log.error('Redis client something went wrong ' + err);
        });
        this.redisClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
            log.info('Redis message received...' + socketClient.id + " socketio emitting to " + channel + ": " + message);
            socketClient.emit('updatemessage', message)
        });
    }

}
```

This is the unit test code:

```
'use strict'

var expect = require('chai').expect
  , server = require('../index')
  , redis = require('redis-mock')
  , redisClient
  , io = require('socket.io-client')
  , ioOptions = { 
      transports: ['websocket']
    , forceNew: true
    , reconnection: false
  }
  , testMsg = JSON.stringify({message: 'HelloWorld'})
  , sender
  , receiver
  



describe('Chat Events', function(){
  beforeEach(function(done){
    
    redisClient = redis.createClient();
    // start the io server
    //server.start()
    // connect two io clients
    sender = io('http://localhost:3000/', ioOptions)
    receiver = io('http://localhost:3000/', ioOptions)
    
    // finish beforeEach setup
    done()
  })
  afterEach(function(done){
    
    redisClient.disconnect
    // disconnect io clients after each test
    sender.disconnect()
    receiver.disconnect()
    done()
  })

  describe('Message Events', function(){
    it('Clients should receive a message when the `message` event is emited.', function(done){
      sender.emit('message', testMsg)
      receiver.on('ackmessage', function(msg){
        expect(msg).to.contains(testMsg)
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you're importing `redis` from `redis-mock` library, it doesn't automatically make Sockets lib using it (and the `redisClient` created with it) under the hood. Instead, it continues relying on "normal" `redis` module.

To achieve that effect, try to add a line at the top:

```
jest.mock('redis', () => redis)
```

right after you're requiring `redis-mock`.

Comment: hm if i'm using mocha, will it still work as it is using jest?

Comment: @user990639, ah, sorry, I was coming fron wrong assumption. With mocha you'll need to mock differently: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki#mocks-stubs--spies